# eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase) = 0, node/client not fully synced yet

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I just started to get my fingertips wet with Ethereum and Dapps.
After receiving some ether on Ropsten to test with:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x05c86fc0ec0b80715f1cbc2fa96e86ba18e2eb90

I can't verify the amount on an attached console (to my syncing geth instance):

eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)
Result: 0

Is this an issue of the node not being synced completely yet?

Cheers,
Mario

Comment: Can you please confirm that `0x5c86...` is your coinbase account? If not can you check it’s balance?

Comment: > eth.coinbase
"0x05c86fc0ec0b80715f1cbc2fa96e86ba18e2eb90", I already checked that they map correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't verify the amount on an attached console (to my syncing geth
>   instance):
>
> eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase) Result: 0

Yes, because geth node didn't get have an updated ledger. Please wait for a while for sync. After sync your block your geth node will show your current balance.

Comment: I thought so, I just wanted to ensure that's the case. The whole technology for me is kinda complex, but it gets better hour by hour and day by day. Thanks for helping out!