# Getting ethers into a Ropsten account

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I am following a course. I have loaded Geth and started it with the following

```
>"c:\program files\geth\geth" --testnet --syncmode fast --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

Truffle is loaded and by executing

```
truffle(default)> web3.personal.newAccount('password')
```

I get back

```
'0x2fd8e5528d094dae7d068ff55587ea5b465a997f'
```

Executing

```
truffle(default)> web3.eth.getBalance('0x2fd8e5528d094dae7d068ff55587ea5b465a997f')
```

returns

```
{ [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
```

Ethers was requested at

```
https://faucet.bitfwd.xyz/
```

using the '0x2fd8e5528d094dae7d068ff55587ea5b465a997f' code but executing getBalance(..) doesn't show any change. How do I get Ethers into that account?

EDIT:
Syncing has been running for 1 day now. I have checked the sync using [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/18610/11293) comment. The current results are

```
{
  currentBlock: 2659248,
  highestBlock: 2659378,
  knownStates: 10005763,
  pulledStates: 9998706,
  startingBlock: 3136
}
```

A new request for Ethers can be seen [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x66062de61f91574fb6197bdd0e6279bfb66b9f6b4cc0b2adcbd6d998b4ddc00c).

Comment: Possibility of duplicate, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39744/eth-getbalanceeth-coinbase-0-node-client-not-fully-synced-yet
Because your local geth is not sync'd

Comment: Edited question: 
I checked syncing via this comment https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/18610/11293

Answer (score 0):

When did you request the ether on the faucet?

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x95a94979d86d9c32d1d2ab5ace2dcc8d1b446fa1
Does not show any recent transaction.

Probably the faucet is empty for now and you should try another one.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't record the transaction ID from the first attempt. I have done it again

[transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x74aa2b052e1a25cf34ab1b6273f2726f440fd01dc8c7917c561298970e923156)

But I still don't see anything in the getBalance. How long should I be waiting?